# Android, activity remembering counting data

Tags: android, counter

Is there any way to activity remebers the counting, because when you start the app, you click the button which random generates an image from drawable, and it doesn't let user to press that button for 30 secs.. the problem now is that when you are waiting for counter go to 0 you can easily press option menu, click settings and click "povratak" ,which starts activity all over again and the counter losses its point because user can now again press button that generates image (and I dont want that):/

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.ams;

import java.util.Random;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Random rnd = new Random();
    ImageView img = null;
    Button btnRandom = null;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(
        final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
        btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);
    }



    protected final static int getResourceID
    (final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
    {
        final int ResourceID =
            ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
                ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (ResourceID == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            (
                "No resource string found with name " + resName
                );
        }
        else
        {
            return ResourceID;
        }
    }

    public void clickHandler(final View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {



        case R.id.btnRandom:
            {
                if (!btnRandom.isEnabled())
                {
                    return;
                }

                // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
                final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(45);
                img.setImageDrawable
                (
                    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                        getApplicationContext()))
                );
                btnRandom.setEnabled(false);

                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) // Wait 30 secs, tick every 1 sec
                {
                    @Override
                    public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
                    {
                        btnRandom.setText("Pričekaj do sljedeće kartice: " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public final void onFinish()
                    {
                        btnRandom.setText("PROMIJENI KARTICU !");
                        btnRandom.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }.start();

                break;
            }


            }

        }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                setContentView(R.layout.help);
                return true;
                    default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    public void goBack(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bgi"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRandom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgRandom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgRandom"
    android:onClick="clickHandler"
    android:text=" Promijeni karticu !"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

help.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:freezesText="false"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="UVOD:Uz svaki scenario organizator moze odrediti da se koristi &quot;AMS sustav&quot; zbog realnijeg pristupa igri i viseg stupnja MILSIM-a. Organizator bira medice (ili kako se vec odredi) i oni moraju imati prilikom pocetka igre 46 kartica. />


</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Povratak" />
```

And if there is possible , show me your answers in code format, cause english is not my native language and often I don't understand what you guys mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is inside the `onPause()` method store the current value of the timer in the `SharedPreferences`. When your app resumes in `onResume()`, you can get that value again, and if it exists start from that.

Comment: Research the Android Lifecycle for more details.

Comment: I'm well aware, thanks. But you are right, considering the wishes of the programmer, something else is probably wanted.

Comment: Comment was for the person with the question. Not sure they are familiar with onPause() and onResume().

Comment: Thanks Evorlor. @GrayFox, you might very well need something else that pause/resume. Quick reference: onResume - onPause marks the timespan in which the user can interact with your app, onStart - onStop the timespan where the app is visible, onCreate - onDestroy where it exists but not necessarily visible.

Comment: I tried but I am new in all this development thing ;) so I don't understand how to put those things together ..

Comment: To be sure; do you want to make the user wait 30 seconds *every time* before he/she can press the button?